# unigram using python

Tags: python, n-gram

i'm trying to generate unigram from a text file. But only the bigram for the first line of the given file is shown. I want to show unigram for all the sentences in the file.

```
import string;
import sys;
import tokenize;

f = open("data.txt", 'r');
line=f.readline();
while line:
    line = line.rstrip();
    list = line.split();
    for word in list:
         print word
    line = f.readline();
```

Why it is not showing unigram for the sentences and also how can i turn this into a bigram?

Thanks in advance.

data.txt is the text file which contains the sentences.
It has two sentences -

```
        Hello world this is a test code
        today is 29th november 2011
```

im getting the output:

```
    Hello
    world
    this
    is
    a
    test
```

code

Comment: It's unclear what you want. What does `data.txt` look like and what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: the output and data.txt file contents are added above

Comment: @larsmans: Look it up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram

Comment: after generating unigrame for the 1st sentence. I also want to show unigram for the 2nd sentence like - 
today
is etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some obvious problems with that code snippet.

1. `;` are not required
2. None of the imported modules (i.e. `tokenize`) are used. This is valid, but pointless.
3. The loop over the file lines uses while, which works but is odd.

You do not show the structure of the text file, but I'm assuming each sentence is on a separate line (i.e. a text file with two sentences will contain two lines).

I'm unsure *exactly* what a bigram is in this case, so you may need to replace the `bigram` function.

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def bigrams(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.strip().split()
        uni = words
        bi = bigrams(words)
        print uni
        print list(bi)
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, if you are using a somewhat current version of python, you can simply do: `for line in f` which is much simpler than this `readline` stuff. Also you don't have to use `;` at every line. It is only used if you want to make several statements in one line.

The following lines work just fine for me:

```
f = open("data.txt", 'r')
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        print word
```

---

To make the *bigram* of a line something like this would suffice (not tested!)

```
items = line.split()
bigrams = []
for i in xrange(len(items) - 1):
    bigrams.append((items[i], items[i + 1]))
```

Comment: +1, the OP seems to just want the tokens out. The `rstrip` is not needed when followed by `split`, btw.

Comment: @larsmans: interesting, didn't think about that :) good point. edited.

Comment: I suggest using `with open('data.txt', 'rU') as f:`.

Comment: Oh and bigrams can be generated with `[(items[i], items[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(items) - 1)]`, not `- 2`.

Comment: larsman, hochl: This is not the *point* of the question and only confuses not experienced programmers. I know how cool Python is, but too complicated constructs just... complicate matters. Especially for beginners. :)